# Android GraphView renders only one date on X Axis

Tags: android, android-graphview

I'm taking stocks date from a database, in which a company's stock history is kept in a DB column. Each day's data is present in the format{date, stock_value}, and is separated form other dates by "\n".

```
    String[] allStocks = history.split("\n");
    String[] singleStock;

    ArrayList<DataPoint> points = new ArrayList<>();
    GraphView graph = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph);

    for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
        {
            singleStock = allStocks[i].split(",");
            Date date = new Date(Long.parseLong(singleStock[0]));
            System.out.println(date);
            points.add(new DataPoint(new Date(Long.parseLong(singleStock[0])), Float.parseFloat(singleStock[1])));
        }

    DataPoint[] dbPoint = points.toArray(new DataPoint[points.size()]);
    System.out.println(points);
    LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>(dbPoint);
    graph.addSeries(series);
    graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setLabelFormatter(new DateAsXAxisLabelFormatter(this));
    graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setNumHorizontalLabels(2); 
    // set manual x bounds to have nice steps

    graph.getViewport().setXAxisBoundsManual(true);

    // as we use dates as labels, the human rounding to nice readable numbers
    // is not necessary
    graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setHumanRounding(false);
```

Following is the content of points variable:
[[1.4887386E12/117.55000305175781], [1.4881338E12/118.62000274658203], [1.4876154E12/118.79000091552734]]

The graph appears as:
[The graph appears only for one date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCzVb.png)

This is the xml for my graph:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:id="@+id/graph" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Only one date appears in the graph. When I try the example code from 'GraphView' for dates everything works as expected. Please let me know if there's any flaw in my code.

Answer (score 0):

I've not worked with GraphView before, but the example I found for dates seemed to be setting the number of horizontal labels to one more than the number of items being graphed, so I would try that:

```
graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setNumHorizontalLabels(points.size()+1);
```